# Create firewall using scapy in python linux, the packet change when she get to the proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, scapy

I have a school project that I need to create a simple firewall using SCAPY.
I chose to create a firewall that its kind of proxy in order to track the packets.
I had to change the default get way to the proxy IP. BUT the problem is that when the client send packets, the proxy get different flags and had ETHERNET layer too, and as result the proxy doesn't get any response back!

I have no idea why it's happen, hope you could help me :)

Comment: the packet that the client send : 
####[IP]####
    version   = 4
    ihl       = None
    tos       = 0x0
    len       = None
    id        = 1
    flags     = 
    frag      = 0
    ttl       = 64
    proto     = icmp
    chksum    = None
    src       = 192.168.217.128
    dst       = 8.8.8.8
    \options   \
####[ICMP]####
    type      = echo-request
    code      = 0
    chksum    = None
    id        = 0x0
    seq       = 0x0
####[Raw]####
    load      = 'Hello World'

Comment: the packet that the proxy get : 
###[ Ethernet ]###
    dst       = 00:0c:29:f2:73:1f
    src       = 00:0c:29:3c:f6:e3
    type      = 0x800
    ###[ IP ]###`
    version   = 4`
    ihl       = 5L
    tos       = 0x0
    len       = 39
    id        = 1
    flags     = 
    frag      = 0L
    ttl       = 64
    proto     = icmp
    chksum    = 0xd09c
    src       = 192.168.217.128
    dst       = 8.8.8.8
    \options   \
###[ ICMP ]###
    type      = echo-request
    code      = 0
    chksum    = 0xa631
    id        = 0x0
    seq       = 0x0
###[ Raw ]###
    load      = 'Hello World'

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right you can use this line:

```
if IP in packet:
    #something to do
```

Then it is not matter if the Ethernet layer exist - because you are asking for the specific layer.

**Good Luck**